# dummy node in generic linked list

Tags: generics, ada, gnat

I'm writing a linked list. Here is my code:

Linked_List.ads

```
generic
   type T is private;
package Linked_List is
   type Node;
   type NodeAccess is access Node;
   type Node is record
      Data : T;
      Next : NodeAccess := null;
   end record;
   type List is record
      Head : NodeAccess;
      Has_Dummy_Head : Boolean;
      Size : Integer;
   end record;
   type ListAccess is access List;
   function Get_New_List(Has_Dummy_Head : Boolean) return ListAccess;
private
   function Get_New_Node(Data : T; Next : NodeAccess) return NodeAccess;
end Linked_List;
```

Linked_List.adb

```
package body Linked_List is
   function Get_New_Node(Data : T; Next : NodeAccess) return NodeAccess is
      New_Node : NodeAccess := new Node;
   begin
      New_Node.all := (Data => Data, Next => Next);
      return New_Node;
   end Get_New_Node;
   function Get_New_List(Has_Dummy_Head : Boolean) return ListAccess is
      New_List : ListAccess := new List;
   begin
      if Has_Dummy_Head = True then
         New_List.all := (Head => Get_New_Node(Data => null, Next => null), Has_Dummy_Head => True, Size => 0);
      else
         New_List.all := (Head => null, Has_Dummy_Head => False, Size => 0);
      end if;
      return New_List;
   end Get_New_List;
end Linked_List;
```

I don't know how to add the Head when the list is with dummy head (Has_Dummy_Head is true). I tried just setting the Data field in the Node to null, but I doesn't work. I don't know how to get some value of type T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using

```
Head => new Node'(Data => <>, Next => null)
```

instead of

```
Head => Get_New_Node(Data => null, Next => null)
```

(or rather defined a constant `Null_Node` or some such).

But in general, not having a value tends to indicate a defect in the organization of the package. Do you really need a dummy head ? Why not simply set the Head pointer to null ? I know that for performance reasons having a dummy head might save a couple of `if Head /= null then` tests, but are you already at that level of optimization ?

Comment: I can't make it work. If I replace
Get_New_Node(Data => null, Next => null)
with Get_New_Node(Data => <>, Next => null)
I "missing operand" error.
If I add ()
 Get_New_Node(Data => (<>), Next => null)
I get "(Ada 2005) box only allowed with named notation" error 
Btw I'm doing this for educational purpose.

Comment: The box notation ("<>") can only be used in aggregates (as I did in the call to `new Node`). You can't pass this as a subprogram call. As I mentioned, you could define a constant (initialized with an aggregate) and pass it to Get_New_Node if you really need. But again, if you need this it might indicate a design that might be better done differently.